# Cannot read float value

Tags: python, hex

trying to read float value but it giving error it says address must be int even though I use read_float and it makes an error it cant read it says address must be int

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *

pm = pymem.Pymem("game.exe")

module = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "game.exe").lpBaseOfDll

def GetPtrAddr(base, offsets):
    addr = pm.read_float(base)
    for i in offsets:
        if i != offsets[-1]:
            addr = pm.read_float(addr + i)
    return addr + offsets[-1]
northsouth = GetPtrAddr(module + 0x01B20C50, [0x38, 0x60, 0x290, 0x68, 0x140, 0x0, 0x3C])
print(pm.read_float(northsouth))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\program\3erfwq.py", line 14, in <module>
    northsouth = GetPtrAddr(module + 0x01B20C50, [0x38, 0x60, 0x290, 0x68, 0x140, 0x0, 0x3C])
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\program\3erfwq.py", line 12, in GetPtrAddr
    addr = pm.read_float(addr + i)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 650, in read_float
    value = pymem.memory.read_float(self.process_handle, address)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 377, in read_float
    bytes = read_bytes(handle, address, struct.calcsize('f'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 97, in read_bytes
    raise TypeError('Address must be int: {}'.format(address))
TypeError: Address must be int: 1994287160.0
```

Comment: What makes you think that `read_float` returns an `int` rather than a `float`?

Comment: I want float but it says address must be int for idk why

Comment: You're setting `addr` to a float value instead of an address. I can't figure out from looking at your code why you chose to do that. But that's obviously wrong and `pymem` is telling you that.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to read multiple floats and then do something with them?

Comment: Oh, is this a simple typo where you meant to write `base + i` instead of `addr +i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [read_float](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.Pymem.read_float) method tries to read a float from a memory address.
The address you specify must be an int - but you are passing a float.

Focus on the argument `addr + i`. Since you initialized `addr = pm.read_float(base)` it definitely is a float, and adding `i` does not change that.

So either initialize using `addr = pm.read_int(base)`, or stay with reading a float but then you have to convert it to an int like so:

```
addr = pm.read_float( int(addr + i) )
```